# Ignore .idea/ files on intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, version-control, ignore

I am working with the intellij IDE, my problem is that always are being added some .idea/ folder files in my intellij after compilation. I had excluded these directory sice: Settings > Version Control > Ignored Files:

[image: Ignored files intellij]

But it seems it is not working, because I continue seeing these files. I am the only one of my team who has this problem, so it should be an IDE problem.

[image]

Comment: There is related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-210702. Please follow it for updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure you already know this, but the .idea directory is actually just the IDE settings generated by IntelliJ IDEA. If you're talking about source control, you'll need to add a rule to ignore that folder.

For git, you'll want a .gitignore file on the project level, and add the following to the file:

```
.idea/
```

If you want to check what is being ignored currently, or add some easy context menus for adding things to your ignore file, install the [".ignore"](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7495--ignore) plugin for IntelliJ-IDEA. This plugin will even let you hide these ignored files, since your IDE will always generate this settings folder in the project directory.